# BF-888 radios don't work with UV-5Rs on the same frequency

Tags: baofeng, ht, radio-programming, tone-squelch, chirp

[image: CHIRP screenshot]I play airsoft here in Quebec Canada, and I have 2 Baofeng BF-888s that I got a few years back. Now people are mostly using UV-5Rs. I used CHIRP to program my radio to the same frequency used by the field so that everyone can talk but even with the right frequency something is wrong. On some channels I can talk but I can't hear on any of the channels. I guess it's something else that is different but I can't seem to find what.

The channel that are used are 1 to 5, the others are the default ones from the factory that I don't use, I only needed 5 channels.

Comment: Salut Marc-André, et bienvenue à ham.stackexchange.com!  We could help you if you give much more information.  Would you please [*edit your question*](https://ham.stackexchange.com/posts/18668/edit) to include a screenshot of CHIRP with the BF-888 channels?

Comment: sorry, not used to that kind of forum, there, edit done.

Comment: I see your channels use tone squelch.  Is the tone frequency set correctly?

Comment: probably not, i dont know what the uv-5r use with the same frequency, for those using it since they can just enter the frequency on the num pad on the radio unlike me who have to use a pc

Comment: Tone squelch is [CTCSS](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/CTCSS).  You can change the frequency by a menu setting without a PC, or you can use CHIRP.

Comment: dont know how to do that on a bf-888s without a pc and i still dont know what ctcss value would be needed to match the uv-5r

Answer (score 1):

You might try changing the **Tone Mode** from *TSQL* to just *Tone*.

*TSQL* mode does two things:

1. sends a tone on transmit
2. requires a tone on receive to break your radio's squelch

*Tone* mode only does one thing: send a tone on transmit.

Comment: i will have to try that, sadly i am not playing before a few week so will be hard to try but thanks