My UV-5r doesn't transmit to Bf-888
I was recently testing my radios to avoid problems like these in advance, and the problem is the following: The UV-5r receives the signal just fine, but when  I use it the two radios don't receive anything. Here are the Chirp screenshots [][]

Screenshots are hard to read.  Dumps from chirp tell us nothing about the state of the radio.   These chirp dumps are not even slightly similar, so I don't see why you think they would work together.  Which memory are the two radios on?  Are you in a memory or in VFO mode on each radio?   Are you using a repeater between the radios?  How close are the two radios?

Sorry for my ignorance, I'm new to the hobby, I'm sorry if I don't know what exactly should I show or do or if I don't know the correct terms, but anyway, the radios are in the same room, and I think that the uv-5r is in memory mode, while the bf-888s are only in memory mode.

Similar question: https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/18668/8717

If that other question doesn't help you, please do edit your question to add answers to @user10489 's comment. And welcome to this site. :-)

Also, https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/22785/8717

I solved it, all I needed to do was to remove the offset on the uv-5r, which solved another problem I had. Thanks for the help

It is important to understand the settings for the channel.
They must match and be appropriate in the two radios to communicate.
The critical settings are:

frequency
mode
duplex (and offset)
tone/dtcs and squelch mode
These settings generally should match between the two radios, but are even more critical if you are trying to use a repeater.

In comment you indicated you changed offset.
Most likely, duplex was on, which assumes there is a repeater between the two radios.  Assuming you changed offset to 0, it would have been equally effective to turn off duplex, which allows the radios to communicate directly rather than through a repeater (simplex).  Make sure you are not using this on a frequency that is also used by a repeater.
